# GET and POST methods retrieval

Tags: android, http, http-post, http-get

I am running a Flask code.. I dont have access to the code but can only run it. Its acting as a server with a URL to hit.
When from browser I hit the URL i am getting the following log in the command line.

```
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/css/normalize.css 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/css/style.css 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET 
/static/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/js/jquery-latest.js 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/res/botim.png 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/js/jquery.min.js 
HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET 
/static/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:03] "GET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 
200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:09] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:13] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:19] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:22] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
172.16.181.145 - - [28/Apr/2017 14:38:26] "POST /message HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

There is a text field in the UI . when write something in text field and press enter. It gives me some response. 
I was writing a simple android code to hit this URL and build same functionality. I need to understand how to send GET request to this URL and receive response from it. Concept/code anything would help. Thanks!

Edit: The URL i am hitting is http://10.158.2.2:5000/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the request:

**Option 1**
If the text field in the browser is a form, you may inspect element to determine the method(POST or GET, probably post) of the form and the name of the inputs.

**Option 2**
Open the Network tab in the inspect element panel in your browser. Enter a value in the text input and submit [press enter]. Examine the request that shows up on submitting the value. Check for the type of request(POST/GET), the URL, Content-Type(probably application/x-www-form-urlencoded) and the PARAMETERS.

After completely understanding the request you may go ahead and implement it in android depending on which library you are using.